# execute Javascript code that is returned res.send()

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am returning (using Node.js) this:

```
var template = '<a href="http://localhost:7000/">Your Account has been activated. </a>';

return res.send(template);
```

What I need to do is to return minimal javascript code that will do automatic redirection rather than a tag.

So far user must click the link, I need it to automatically redirect.

Thoughts?

Comment: Returning it to what? I assume you're making an AJAX request, so you'd want to do something like: `window.location.href = xmlhttp.responseText;` when handling a success (200) status code, and simply return the URL to redirect to.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you use ajax and that you return HTML in your response. You can just return javascript :

```
var template =  '<script type="text/javascript"> window.location.href="http://localhost:7000"; </script>';
return res.send(template);
```

And then append it to your document. But it's not the cleanest solution.

You could just return the link, and use it in your ajax complete callback.

Answer (score 2):

You can set location header:

```
res.setHeader('Location', 'http://someurl.com');
```

[nodejs http docs](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_setheader_name_value)

Comment: I am not using Ajax. The user receives the link in his mail. He clicks on the link, and it takes him to REST endpoint that takes the hash code and activates the account.

Comment: `res.redirect('...')` is shorter :)

Comment: @robertklep Afaik `.redirect` is from the express api. And does it work with external links?

Comment: @NULL `res.send()` is Express as well, isn't it? And yes, should work with external URL's too.